# How to replace duplicated value from a table to "quantity"?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

Im trying to make a typical webshop, got everything worked out so far, but I got this following issue: **How do I replace duplicate database-value in a List to quantity instead, and list them into ListView?** E.g. if I add two of same product into my cart, I want to be able to show quantity instead showing two of same product in the cart-list.

PS: Im listing my results in ListView.

(Form_Load for cart):

```
using (eShopEntities db = new eShopEntities()){

            var list = new List<Product>(db.Products.ToList());

            var listFilter = new List<Product>(); 

            foreach (var id in list)
            {
                foreach (var Sessions in SessionData)//got selected products stored in sessions
                {
                    if (id.ID == Sessions)
                    {

                        listFilter.Add(id); //Add all selected products(via session)
                    }
                }
            }

            int TotSum = 0;
            foreach (var sum in listFilter)
            {
                TotSum = TotSum + sum.Price;

            }

            cartListView.DataSource = listFilter; cartListView.DataBind();

            lblSum.Text = TotSum.ToString();


           }
```

Right now, everything is listed in aspx. But Im not sure how to replace duplicated into quantities from listFilter **AND** send the quanties-data along with the result from listFilter into cartListWiev togheter.

My Product table(SQL): ID(PK), Name, ImagePath, Price, and CatergoryID(FK)

Thanks

Comment: var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.Name).select({ y=> new  Product() { Name = y.Name, Price = y.Sum(y1=>y1.Price)  }   }).ToList() ; I guess you are looking for GroupBy based on Name.

Comment: Thanks but I couldnt make it work, getting following error for "select"-part: "Cannot resolve symbol 'select' / "IEnumerable<|Igrouping<string, Product>> does not contain definition for 'select' ...". I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Add System.Linq to reference and try to search about linq grouby sum,it must help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of possibilities (not obligatory the best one, but technically it should work) you can change your code like that:

```
using (eShopEntities db = new eShopEntities()){

            IDictionary<long, int> productQuantities = new Dictionary<long, int>(); // supposed your product.ID is of type long
            var list = new List<Product>(db.Products.ToList());

            var listFilter = new List<Product>(); 

            foreach (var id in list)
            {
                foreach (var Sessions in SessionData)//got selected products stored in sessions
                {
                    if (id.ID == Sessions)
                    {
                        if (!productQuantities.ContainsKey(id.ID)) // new
                        { 
                         listFilter.Add(id); //Add all selected products(via session)
                         productQuantities.Add(id.ID, 1)
                        } // new else {
                         productQuantities[id.ID]++; // new                         
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            int TotSum = 0;
            foreach (var sum in listFilter)
            {
                // TotSum = TotSum + sum.Price; // old

                sum.Quantity = productQuantities[id.ID]; // supposed your class Product has corresponding property for quantities
                TotSum = TotSum + sum.Price * sum.Quantity;
            }

            cartListView.DataSource = listFilter; cartListView.DataBind();

            lblSum.Text = TotSum.ToString();


           }
```

Comment: That was a good solution, no more duplicated were shown in the result. However, I dont know how to use productQuantities properly and show its result along with listFilter in ListView since im not familiar with the Dictionary. 

I compromised this part by adding a Quantity property for Product-table, but I've to reset its value to 0 here and there then. And im not sure that's a proper way. I really think the productQuantities + listFilter combo is the way to go. Is there and good way to do it?

Comment: Hi @Nyprez, thank you for your response. With the property **Product.Quantity** it was just an example how you can take quantities into account. If you need quantity only to calculate the total sum, you can do it simply so: `TotSum = TotSum + productQuantities[id.ID]`. If you need to show quantities explicitly in your listView, you can for example update your product names (for ListView only) like `sum.Name = sum.Name + ' ' + productQuantities[id.ID]`. As quantity is only temporarily needed, there is no real need to add that as field into your database table.